# Pre Loader and Page loading image with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using a Pre-loader which disappear when all the page's images are loaded.

The problem is that some of my page, portfolio and blog are using Ajax to call the posts.

Of course the pre-loader finish before all the posts requested by ajax are loaded, so when the pre-loader disappear my page is still getting the posts and not fully loaded.

I tried to start the preloader function using ajaxComplete

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(evt){
$('body').jpreLoader();
});
```

it's perfect for the pages using ajax, but of course doesn't work when the pages doesn't use Ajax.

I am looking for a way to wait before removing the pre-loader overlay when the page got an Ajax call an to remove it directly if no Ajax call in the page.

Thanks in advance, doesn't hesitate to tell me if you need more information or if something is unclear.

Comment: Could you not just have both ajaxComplete and ready listeners?

Comment: I think if I use both the preloader script will be loaded and finished before the ajax call in the page has been loaded.

Comment: How about putting the `.jpreLoader()` in the complete function on the AJAX call?

Comment: Page that doesn't use an Ajax Call wont be able to load the preloader function, the preloader function is the one that check if images are loaded and hide the page overlay